# htaccess: how to rewrite url for any /abc but some /files

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'd like to enable URls rules in my domain with alphanumeric like

```
example.org/w2He4x
```

to go to

```
example.org/url.php?id=w2He4x
```

but at the same time I want to prevent to have regular links like

`example.org/login` 
to go to 
`example.org/url.php?id=login`

what's the rule to do that in my htaccess?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using something such as this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /url.php?id=$1 [L]
```

It should rewrite the query string parameter only (eg. `w2He4x`). If you want to disallow certain parameters then you'll want to make rules that forbid them.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be simpler to use url.php to test for a valid id and return an error or forbidden if the id isn't valid.